# facebook api to get user albums , photos in wordpress page

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a Wordpress page to get user albums, and photos for each album using Facebook API

Here is my code :

```
    function myFBcall(){
         FB.login(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              if (response.authResponse) {
                   console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                   FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,albums,photos', function(myalb) {

                   console.log(myalb);
                   jQuery( "#facebookimages" ).html('<h3>My Albums :</h3>');    

                   jQuery.each( myalb.albums.data, function( i, val ) {
                   /* make the API call */
                   FB.api(
                        "/"+val.id+"/picture",
                        function (mycover) {
                             if (mycover && !mycover.error) {

                         jQuery( "#facebookimages" ).append( "<div class='myalbum'
                         onClick='javascript:getmyphotos(\""+val.id+"\",\""+val.name+"\")' ><img src='"+mycover.data.url+"' width='90%' height='90%'/>"+val.name+"</div>" );    
                             }
                        }
                  );
                  });
             });
          } else {
               console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
          }
    },{ 'scope': 'user_photos,publish_actions','return_scopes': true });
    }
```

its working correctly with user registered in my Facebook app as developer or administrator

but not working with my WordPress users

how to make it working with all users in my wordpress website ??

any help ??

Comment: did you make your app online/public in 'status & review' tab of the FB application?

Comment: yes its online / public 
here is the app review image 
http://awesomescreenshot.com/03f35kyc50

Comment: are you getting any errors with other users?

Comment: i am not getting errors for login , but the error in consol.log myalb.albums.data not defiend , i believe the problem may from facebook app permission , but i read that wordpress not need extended permission for albums and photos

Comment: i got the permission for wordpress users using console.log , it says  ->>
[ grantedScopes: "public_profile" ] ,
 but for the developers of the facebook app :
[ grantedScopes: "public_profile ,user_photos" ]

then how to get ( user_photos ) permission working in wordpress for all users ? i read that wordpress not need this permission , any help please ?

Comment: While I don't have specific knowledge about wordpress, in general, you would need to ask those permissions. If your app was created after april 30, asking for extended permissions require Facebook approval. Read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/04/30/the-new-facebook-login

Comment: thank you Ibrahim , your replied is wokring with me , i asked for ( user_photos) permission and facebook approved ,  its working now ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `While I don't have specific knowledge about wordpress, in general, you would need to ask those permissions. If your app was created after april 30, asking for extended permissions require Facebook approval. Read more here: developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/04/30/… –  Ibrahim yesterday`

**thank you Ibrahim , your replied is wokring with me , i asked for ( user_photos) permission and facebook approved , its working now ,**